# Outlook - Using .ost file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I recently got a new computer, and made a backup of all my Outlook .pst files on the old machine. I imported these to the new machine (unfortunately after I already created the email profiles there), and since a few days two of my accounts have not been updated with new mails (even though I can verify through webmail I did in fact receive some new mails).

Checking the mailbox location on the new machine, it points to %user%\AppData\Microsoft\Outlook, and in there, it refers to some .ost file. Ost apparently hints at Offline files, which might explain why the new mails won't show up.

I tried copying my .ost file, followed by removing and recreating the user, but that simply creates a new .ost file. Why would it somehow suddenly switch to that, and how can I fix it so that I will receive new mails again?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: Why the downvote, exactly? I tried describing my issue as well as I could, and provided things I tried. Not sure why that would somehow warrant a downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound I could, yes. I tested several times, and the only thing it really failed to do was obtaining new mails. I found a solution though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what to do. If anyone else ever finds themselves in the same situation, here's how I solved it.

I removed the account, and then created it again, this time manually supplying all the info. When doing so, you can select what file to use. Rather than have Outlook create a new one, I selected to use the copy of my .pst file, and that did the trick nicely.

Comment: @sunk818 - We're not using an exchange server, but rather a pop3 server. Mails are regularly purged from there, so I prefer having things collected in my Outlook :)